# Joomla 2.5 - Problem with scaling (resizing) images in editor

Tags: joomla, images

I have very strange problem with inserting and then scaling images in Joomla editor (Joomla version 2.5, clean install).

Insert button works normal, but I'm unable to scale image (drag by corners). If I right click on the image, then suddenly appear same image (at this point I have two images in my editor, even if I inserted only one). One of that two images is 'ghost' image and it disappear as soon as I save my article.

After saving article I can scale images without problem.

I've tried to change editors, and on all of them is same problem.

This is my first Joomla 2.5 installation and I've never had such problems before..

Anyone have idea how to solve this?

edit: I just clean installed Joomla, and its same. Tried to add content from different machines (Windows, Ubuntu, Mint) same problem. Also tried different browser, again same problem.

edit2: On Joomla 1.5 everything works normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it doesn't answer your question directly - but I really recommend on re-sizing the pictures on your computer in a way that will also reduce the image size, for example,
if you upload a 300KB picture and resize it to a size of 70KB picture (on Joomla) you're doing two bad things:
1. You're making the page heavier to load than it should be
2. You're damaging your rank - cause you'll be wasting your "crawl budget" (from SEO perspective)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Valid point, but in Joomla you can install some plugins which will resize  and compress scaled image, so there will no be speed issues. Even inserting small and optimized images is a problem in my installation.

Comment: @RhymeGuy good to know! do you happened to have a link or remember a name of such plugin ?

Comment: I use BK-Multithumb located here http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images/articles-images/9346
There are also other extensions at http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images/articles-images